# Selenium Mobile sequence for setting up the test methods, Assembly Initialize and tear down

Tags: selenium

How would I set assembly initialize and tear down and then test methods for selenium mobile. 
I have tried to follow the sequence as we do for selenium but for mobile it didn't work out.

Here is the code I am currently using to start my driver. I would like to run this setup before each test, and appropriate teardown steps after the test is complete:

```
// start appium service
var builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
var appiumLocalService = builder.UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
appiumLocalService.Start();

// create appium driver capabilities
var options = new AppiumOptions { PlatformName = "Android" };
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 3a Pie 9.0 - API 28");

// add app or appPackage / appActivity depending on preference
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp");

options.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2"); // this one is important

// these are optional, but I find them to be helpful -- see DesiredCapabilities Appium docs to learn more
options.AddAdditionalCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("allowSessionOverride", true);


// start the driver
var driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(appiumLocalService.ServiceUrl, options);
```

Comment: SO i have to add capabilities in every single test method? can't i just put them in one of the initialize and then just use the driver like that? similar to the way its done in selenium.

Comment: lets say i put this in Assemby insitialize then if create another testmethod and do class, when i call driver.findelment "driver" errors out how would it be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# with NUnit, you can use the NUnit included `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` attributes to accomplish this. If you would like to apply this scenario to all of your tests, you can put these methods into a separate `Fixture` class that will inherit each of these methods.

Here's a very basic setup to get you started:

```
public class Fixture
{
    public AndroidDriver<IWebElement> Driver { get; }
    private AppiumLocalService _appiumLocalService;

   [SetUp]
   public void StartDriver()
    {
        // start appium service
        var builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        _appiumLocalService = builder.UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
        _appiumLocalService.Start();

         // create appium driver capabilities
        var options = new AppiumOptions { PlatformName = "Android" };
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 3a Pie 9.0 - API 28");

        // add app or appPackage / appActivity depending on preference
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp");

        options.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2"); // this one is important

        // these are optional, but I find them to be helpful -- see DesiredCapabilities Appium docs to learn more
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("allowSessionOverride", true);


        // set the driver global variable
        Driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(appiumLocalService.ServiceUrl, options);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void CloseDriver()
    {
        Driver.Close(); // may need to change Driver.CloseApp();
        Driver.Quit();

        // stop appium service
        _appiumLocalService.Stop();
    }
```

Now, when you create a class for a test case, it will look like this:

```
public class MyTestClass : Fixture
{
    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        // perform test functions here such as FindElement and SendKeys
        Driver.FindElement("myElement");
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunAnotherTest()
    {
        // these tests use different driver instances, but that code will never have to be duplicated!
    }
}
```

**Note** that you can create as many test classes as you want to inherit from `Fixture` and you will **never** have to duplicate the driver declaration code, or even call it.

Now, let's break down what is going on here. NUnit `[Setup]` and `[TearDown]` attributes designate a method that will run before everything tagged with `[Test]`. So, if NUnit runs a `[Test]` method, it will run `[SetUp]` > `[Test]` > `[TearDown]`. This is very useful, because you do not have to duplicate code for actions that need to be repeated over and over again.

In `Fixture`, we have a global `Driver` variable that represents the `AndroidDriver<>` instance for **this particular test**. The `Driver` instances is created from scratch in `[SetUp]` before the test, used during the `[Test]` method, and once the `[Test]` is finished, `[TearDown]` will destroy the `Driver` instance. The process repeats for every test. This type of usage where we create exactly one instance of an object for re-use throughout a process is called the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

This ensures your `Driver` instance does not get re-used between test cases, which is preferred practice in test automation.

We have also declared `_appiumLocalService` as a private variable, because while we do not need to use this variable outside of `Fixture`, we still need to re-use the variable between `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` so we can stop the Appium service once our test is finished.

Comment: I also created a testmethod by using chrome options as well. Thanks

Comment: Glad to see you got it working. This is the base framework that I use for all of my automation projects, so I am happy to share.